# How to include .aar dependency into Android library .aar file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, aar, maven-publish

I write some library, which **has a portion of UI**. Also, this library **uses another libraries**.
I want to provide release `.aar` to use this **portion of UI** in any App.

My library has next dependecies:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary:stated-fragment-support-v4:0.10.0'

    //Http communication, websockets, etc.
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'

    //Fonts
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'

    //Unit tests
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'

    //Other
    compile ('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }

    //Reactive programmnig
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.25.0'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
```

When I built `.aar` everything is fine, but when I inlude this `.aar` into another app, I have next problems:

**1).** `./gradlew clean build`

> /home/user/projects/MainApp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.my.sdk/SDK/0.0.1/res/values/values.xml:78:21-29
>   : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'fontPath'.
>
> /home/user/projects/MainApp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.my.sdk/SDK/0.0.1/res/values/values.xml:78:21-29
>   : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'fontPath'.
>
> /home/user/projects/MainApp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.my.sdk/SDK/0.0.1/res/values/values.xml:78:21-29
>   : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'fontPath'.
>
> /home/user/projects/MainApp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.my.sdk/SDK/0.0.1/res/values/values.xml:78:21-29
>   : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'fontPath'.
>
> /home/user/projects/MainApp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.my.sdk/SDK/0.0.1/res/values/values.xml:78:21-29
>   : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'fontPath'.
>
> /home/user/projects/MainApp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.my.sdk/SDK/0.0.1/res/values/values.xml:78:21-29
>   : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'fontPath'.
>
> :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Solution is very simple - add to `MainApp/app/build.gradle` next line:

`compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'`

**2).** When I run `MainApp` getting this error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.my.sdk.ui.fragment.DialogAppNotInstalledFragment`

To solve this I need to add `compile 'com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary:stated-fragment-support-v4:0.10.0'` to `MainApp/app/build.gradle`.

Same to other dependecies.

In the result I need just `copy-paste` all my dependecies from my `library` project to `MainApp` project.

Is it possible to make `library aar` contain all necessery dependecies?

**`build.gradle` of library:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
//apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude '.readme'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary:stated-fragment-support-v4:0.10.0'

    //Http communication, websockets, etc.
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'

    //Fonts
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'

    //Unit tests
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'

    //Other
    compile ('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }

    //Reactive programmnig
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.25.0'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
}

// To publish to maven local execute "gradle clean build publishToMavenLocal"
// To publish to nexus execute "gradle clean build publish"
android.libraryVariants
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            artifact "${project.buildDir}/outputs/aar/${project.name}-release.aar"
            artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
            groupId = GROUP
            version = VERSION_NAME

            // Task androidSourcesJar is provided by gradle-mvn-push.gradle
            //artifact androidSourcesJar {
            //    classifier "sources"
            //}
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username System.getenv('NEXUS_USER_NAME')
                password System.getenv('NEXUS_PASSWORD')
            }
            url "http://my-nexus-url/"
        }
    }
}
```

**`MainApp/app/build.gradle`**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'http://my-nexus-url/' }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}


android {
    signingConfigs {
        some_config {
            keyAlias 'some alias'
            keyPassword '741789654uppy'
            storeFile file('../my-keystore.jks')
            storePassword 'some_password'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.app.android"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.some_config
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/StartAppInApp-2.3.1.jar')
//    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/applovin-sdk-5.2.0.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //here is my library!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    compile('com.my.sdk:SDK:0.0.1@aar'){
        transitive = true;
        exclude(group:'android.support', module: 'support-v4')
    }


    //***********************************************
    //Dependecies from library
    //***********************************************
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.25.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile ('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile 'com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary:stated-fragment-support-v4:0.10.0'
    //************************************************
}
```

## UPDATE

Generated `POM` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.my.sdk</groupId>
<artifactId>SDK</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>aar</packaging>
</project>
```

Comment: Examine your library's generated POM file and confirm that it lists all the dependencies.

Comment: @CommonsWare, it doesn't contain any dependecies, how can I solve it?(I added pom file to question)

Comment: I do not use the `maven-publish` plugin personally, so I do not know where things are going wrong. But, if you can get your POM fixed, that should solve your overall problem.

Comment: @Alexander Were you able to fix this issue? I am facing a very similar issue at my end. Can you help?

Answer (score -3):

If anybody have the same problem, you may obtain correct answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34514023/1796309)
Result `build.gradle` is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude '.readme'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary:stated-fragment-support-v4:0.10.0'

    //Http communication, websockets, etc.
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'

    //Fonts
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'

    //Unit tests
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'

    //Other
    compile ('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }

    //Reactive programmnig
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.25.0'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
}


// To publish to maven local execute "gradle clean build publishToMavenLocal"
// To publish to nexus execute "gradle clean build publish"
android.libraryVariants
publishing {

    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            artifact "${project.buildDir}/outputs/aar/${project.name}-release.aar"
            artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
            groupId = GROUP
            version = VERSION_NAME

            pom.withXml {
                def depsNode  = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

                configurations.compile.allDependencies.each {  dep ->
                    if(dep.name != null && dep.group != null && dep.version != null) {
                        def depNode = depsNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        depNode.appendNode('groupId', dep.group)
                        depNode.appendNode('artifactId', dep.name)
                        depNode.appendNode('version', dep.version)
                        //optional add scope
                        //optional add transitive exclusions
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username System.getenv('NEXUS_USER_NAME')
                password System.getenv('NEXUS_PASSWORD')
            }
            url "http://nexus-repository-url/"
        }
    }
}
```